# SSRS Multivalue parameter contains blanks - Query the blank in multivalue parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, parameter-passing, ssrs-2012, multivalue

I have a SSRS multivalue parameter called @prmEstate which is a list of dates. The dataset to populate @prmEstate is

```
select distinct [forecast finish]
from table1
```

The [forecast finish] column contains some blank values. I want to be able to pass in or select the blank value at runtime so I can see only records have a blank [forecast finish] or include the blank value records in the select all records. The line in my main dataset is

```
    SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE2
    WHERE ([forecast finish] IN @prmEstate)
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Are the records actually datetime colums?  So when you say blank you mean null?  Or are the dates varchar() and they really are empty strings?

Comment: Yes, they are actually datetime columns. Blank means null, no data there at all. Thank you.

Comment: I see.  Multivalue parameters do not allow null values.  To solve this, I would add another parameter that is boolean and asks if you want to include null dates.  Then in the query and the check in the where add (( @BooleanParam = 1 and table.date is null) or (@BooleanParam = 0 and table.date is not null))